# CSS for IE 8 and below - div background image size

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, background-image

I have a div whith the following style:

```
.pricemark {
  background: url(/Files/System/ui/vispris.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 110%;
  background-size: 30%\9; }
```

However, in IE8 and below the image-size 110% is interpreted as 110% of the image size whereas all other browsers sees this as the div size.

Hence, in IE8 and below it's not shown correct. I've attempted the hack:

```
background-size: 30%\9;
```

But the result is still the same. Any ideas?

Comment: can you share your site where we can see what have you talking about

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and below do not support the background-size property.

One way to deal with it would be:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='/Files/System/ui/vispris.png',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='/Files/System/ui/vispris.png',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Comment: Only problem here is that the image from 'background' remains. Hence they overlap... have tried to tweek it but so far no luck

Comment: yes, background-size and the ms filter do not work exactly in the same way and even with the filter it is still a pain in the ass to get the same solution as background-size, but it is the only css based solution I know of.